# How do I use TestNG with Apache Ivy?

Tags: java, ant, ivy, testng

I tried to use [TestNG](http://testng.org/) with [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), but was unsuccessful. Here is my `ivy.xml`:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">

    <info organisation="me" module="myproject"/>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="5.8" />
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

This fails to actually download a TestNG jarfile. It seems to be because TestNG has a jarfile for jdk14 and jdk15. Here's the output from `ivy:retrieve`:

```
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: me#myproject;working@jared-mbp17
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  found org.testng#testng;5.8 in public
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 1139ms :: artifacts dl 11ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   1   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      [FAILED     ] org.testng#testng;5.8!testng.jar:  (0ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    /Users/jared/.ivy2/shared/org.testng/testng/5.8/jars/testng.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/5.8/testng-5.8.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: org.testng#testng;5.8!testng.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

In the repository you can see two different jarfiles:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/5.8/testng-5.8-jdk14.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/5.8/testng-5.8-jdk15.jar

How do I specify either `jdk14` or `jdk15`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the classifier of the artifact you want.

There is a related [fix as of 2.1.0-RC1](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1041). You can use the element `artifact` within the `dependency` element to specify the `classifier` you want. In this case, the classifier should be `jdk14` or `jdk15`. If you want `jdk15` your `ivy.xml` would then be:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0"
            xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">

    <info organisation="me" module="myproject"/>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="5.8"
                  transitive="false">
        <artifact name="testng" type="jar" ext="jar" e:classifier="jdk15" />
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Note the specification of the XML namespace `"http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra"` as an attribute of the `ivy-module` element. Without that the `e:classifier` won't work.